# Why when changing character mesh alpha color to 0 it's not making the character disappearing slowly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main idea is to create some kind of disappearing slowly effect so when the character is getting on a teleporter it will make the character disappearing slowly like transfer the player slowly through the teleporter.

The character mesh renderer is a child of the character :

[Character inspector mesh settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YvaS.jpg)

If in the editor I disable the Skinned Mesh Renderer it will make the character disappearing not slowly but the character will disappear.

Next is to add a script to the teleporter and then try to change the character mesh alpha color from 255 to 0 :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public Renderer rendererToGetMaterial;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.1f;
    public bool toTeleport = false;

    private List<Vector3> teleportersPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        teleporters.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleporter"));

        if (teleporters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GameObject teleporter in teleporters)
            {
                teleportersPositions.Add(teleporter.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Teleport(other.gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Teleport(GameObject objectToTeleport)
    {
        TeleportingVisualEffect(objectToTeleport);
    }

    private void TeleportingVisualEffect(GameObject objectToTeleport)
    {
        var material = rendererToGetMaterial.material;
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, 0f, 3f));
    }

    // Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
    // Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
    // and the number of seconds to fade over.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {

        // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
        float t = 0;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            // Step the fade forward one frame.
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            // Apply the resulting color to the material.
            material.color = color;

            // Wait one frame, and repeat.
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When running the game I can see it's changing the vanguard_Mesh shader color alpha to 0 I also tried to change it on my own before running the game but it's not making the character disappear slowly.

It does nothing to the character.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/863381/how-do-i-change-the-transparency-of-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Just changing the alpha color will not work if the Rendering Mode is set to Opaque.
To make it work I had to change the Rendering Mode to Transparent.

Since there is no a direct access to the Rendering Mode property I created a small new class for it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public static class MaterialExtensions
{
    public static void ToOpaqueMode(this Material material)
    {
        material.SetOverrideTag("RenderType", "");
        material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.One);
        material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.Zero);
        material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 1);
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
        material.renderQueue = -1;
    }

    public static void ToFadeMode(this Material material)
    {
        material.SetOverrideTag("RenderType", "Transparent");
        material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
        material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
        material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
        material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
        material.renderQueue = (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderQueue.Transparent;
    }
}
```

And then using it with a script in this case my script in the question :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public Renderer rendererToGetMaterial;
    public float fadeSpeed = 0.1f;
    public bool toTeleport = false;

    private List<Vector3> teleportersPositions = new List<Vector3>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        teleporters.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Teleporter"));

        if (teleporters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GameObject teleporter in teleporters)
            {
                teleportersPositions.Add(teleporter.transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Teleport(other.gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void Teleport(GameObject objectToTeleport)
    {
        TeleportingVisualEffect(objectToTeleport);
    }

    private void TeleportingVisualEffect(GameObject objectToTeleport)
    {
        var material = rendererToGetMaterial.material;
        MaterialExtensions.ToFadeMode(material);
        StartCoroutine(FadeTo(material, 0f, 3f));
    }

    // Define an enumerator to perform our fading.
    // Pass it the material to fade, the opacity to fade to (0 = transparent, 1 = opaque),
    // and the number of seconds to fade over.
    IEnumerator FadeTo(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration)
    {

        // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
        Color color = material.color;
        float startOpacity = color.a;

        // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
        float t = 0;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            // Step the fade forward one frame.
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
            float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

            // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
            color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

            // Apply the resulting color to the material.
            material.color = color;

            // Wait one frame, and repeat.
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This line :

```
MaterialExtensions.ToFadeMode(material);
```

Now the effect is working perfect. and now I can set a random position of the character to move to another teleporter and then using the ToOpaqueMode method.